# Simple way of pushing view controller on iPhone and presenting as a form sheet on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Getting back into iPad dev after focusing on iPhone only for a while. I have a checkout view that I want to be pushed into a nav stack on iPhone, but presented in a modal form sheet on iPad. In a iOS 9+ world, is there a way to do this that does not involve doing something like

```
if ipad {
  self.presentViewController()
} else {
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true
}
```

That method is somewhat simple. I mostly want to know if there's something I'm missing in terms of using `traitCollections` and some of the new adaptive bits iOS has added over the years that I'm missing.

To be clear, I'm not looking for different ways of doing the `if` statement. I looking if there is one method I can call that will automatically present/push as applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using size classes to accomplish this. Even on iPad, there are situations in which you would have a skinny view, for which pushing the view on would still make sense. For example, if your app supported slide-over multitasking and you launched it as a slideover app, it would have a width of 300 points.

You can access the horizontalSizeClass through your view or view controller's traitCollection.

```
if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
    // present it
} else {
    // push it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to do that but you can find a solution with [UIUserInterfaceIdiom](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfaceidiom) using it like that :

```
    switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .pad:
        break // iPad
    case .phone:
        break // iPhone
    case .carPlay:
        break
    case .tv:
        break
    case .unspecified:
        break
    }
```